# Total current month disappeared with the new year

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

Today it's 1/1/2024 and the total Current Month in my Power BI dashboard is not showing since today:

[image]

That measure is calculated this way:

This is how it's calculated:

```
Total Current Month = CALCULATE(
    'Costs Summary Table'[Sum of measures],
     FILTER(
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1) &&
        'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() -2
    )
)
```

There are no filters applied.

Why passing from 2023 to 2024 broke my dashboard?

Comment: Yes, @SamNseir was right, I just had to wait for the 3rd day of the month to have this Problem  fixed automatically. This is the first time I see this and I suspect it happens only between years and not between month. 
I will wait till the end of this month to check again. Thank you for caring

Comment: It also happens between months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Davide already mentioned, your current logic is: give me this month's value upto two days before today. So it will always return null for the first 2 (or 3 days) of **each** new month.

Comment: Well, I have to check that

Answer (score 1):

Is your filter not equating to the following: greater than or equal to 1st Jan 2024 but less than or equal to 30 December 2023? i.e. no dates will match that filter?

Comment: Do you mean that this problem will just go away after February has started?

Comment: I mean the intersection of your two criteria is null. When you get to 3rd or maybe 4th Jan, it will start working again.

Comment: What is the purpose of TODAY() - 2? I don't understand why you would ever need it

Comment: Your current logic is give me this month's  value upto two days before today. So it will always return null for the first 2 (or 3 days) of each new month.

Comment: @SamNseir, your suggestion was right, today it's the 3 of January and the problem is solved. Please publish that as an answer and I will upvote it. Thank you

Comment: Davide was first on this with his second comment. Question to you is why the `TODAY() - 2`? Why not just  `TODAY() `?

Comment: @SamNseir this because these data are pulled from the Azure Cost Management. Microsoft says that the last 5 days should always be taken by grain of salt as the totals are recalculated. From my experience I see that 2 days is usually enough. 
So that -2 is just for focusing on what we think are real totals.

Comment: @SamNseir do you think you are going to post your answer. I'm going to upvote if you do so. Otherwise I'm going to post it myself. I just wanted to thank you for your help